# Installing Spark on Windows not working

Tags: java, windows, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to install Apache Spark on my Windows 10 computer. My first step to install Spark was to download [Java from here](https://java.com/en/download/) it was then downloaded through this path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` the one folder that was downloaded during this installation was: `\jre1.8.0_151`

Next I installed the [JDK from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and downloaded the windows x86 version. I used the same path as above in the Java folder to download it. After it was done I had two folders inside the Java folder: `jdk1.8.0_151 and jre1.8.0_151`

Afterwards, I set the JAVA_HOME variable to point to `C:\PROGRA~1(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151` and in `Path` I added `%JAVA_HOME%` I then installed [Scala from here](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/) and downloaded the Scala binaries for Windows. The environment path was added in `path` as: `C:\PROGRA~1(x86)\scala\bin`

Next I installed [Spark from here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) and installed `spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz` Afterwards, I placed this folder here `D:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7`I then added the environment variable as SPARK_HOME with the path: `D:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin` and I then updated `path` to `%SPARK_HOME%\bin`

Finally I tried to see if everything was installed. I typed `java -version` and the correct java was installed. I then typed `scala` and scala was open for me to type in expressions and such. I then typed in `spark-shell` but I got this error:

> 'spark-shell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

What am I doing wrong that is not making spark open? Please note: I am using cmd for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you set your `%SPARK_HOME%` to a wrong place and thus when  "*I then updated `path` to `%SPARK_HOME%\bin`*" it resulted in adding `D:\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\bin` with double `\bin` which is obviously wrong. `%SPARK_HOME%` should be without `\bin`.

Generally you can test your environment variables by calling `echo %PATH%` in the command line or `SET` to show all of them

Comment: Hmm I see, when I updated this it still gives me an error saying: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: @user2896120, which one did you adjust `%PATH%` or `%SPARK_HOME%`? I believe you need to adjust `%SPARK_HOME%` because `spark-shell.cmd` indirectly calls `"%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit2.cmd"` which relies on the no `\bin` in the `%SPARK_HOME%`. If this is not the case, you probably should edit  all the `.cmd` files under the `bin` folder adding `REM ` (i.e. commenting) before `@echo off` in their first line. In such way you can find out which command has failed. Without knowing it I don't know how to help you.

Comment: It's working now, the problem was with the java_home I had to remove the (x86) in the path!

Comment: @user2896120, yeah, I missed that mistake. It's good you've found it too.

Comment: Thank you @SergGr ! you saved my life !